# Getting functions to process in order with JQuery $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to first run through a loop of AJAX API calls inside the **populateStreamerCards** function and then when that is finished, run through a loop of AJAX calls for different data.

After reading up on **$.when**, it seems I have to return a **promise** object from my first function but I'm not sure the syntax to do that.

```
var streamers = ["dreadztv", "lirik", "freecodecamp", "LCK1", "ESL_SC2"];

function populateStreamerCards () {
    var twitchPassThroughAPI = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/";
    var streamerSection = document.getElementById("streamers");

    // Loop through to populate the cards.
    for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
        // Get data from the 'channels' portion of the API and populate the cards
        $.ajax( {
            url: twitchPassThroughAPI + streamers[i],
            dataType: 'jsonp', // jsonp helps with cross origin error
            type: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Twitch API App': 'v.1' }, 
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)); // Shows the whole returned object nicely formatted for debugging 
                // Populate cards with the channel data
                var card = document.createElement('div');
                card.className = 'card';
                card.id = 'user-' + data.display_name;

                // Populate the card with streamer data
                card.innerHTML = '<img class="card-img-top" src="' + data.logo + '" alt="Stream Image">\
                                  <div class="card-block">\
                                    <h4 class="card-title">' + data.display_name + '</h4>\
                                    <p class="card-text">' + data.status + '</p>\
                                    <a href="' + data.url +'" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>\
                                  </div>'; 

                // Append the card to the streamer section
                streamerSection.appendChild(card);
            }
        });
    }
}

$.when( populateStreamerCards() ).done(function() {
    alert('Now it is time to check if they are online');
    var twitchPassThroughAPI = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/";

    // Loop through to fade the cards of offline streamers
    for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {

        $.ajax( {
            url: twitchPassThroughAPI + streamers[i],
            dataType: 'jsonp', // jsonp helps with cross origin error
            type: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Twitch API App': 'v.1' }, 
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.stream == null){
                    // The streamer is offline. Add the offline class to fade out the card
                    $( "#user-" + streamer ).addClass( "offline" );

                    // Change the button text to Offline and disable it
                } 
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: `$.when` takes 1 to n arguments ... the resulting `.then` receives 1 to n arguments - 1 to 1 map of the input arguments to `$.when` ... any arguments to `$.when` that are promises will be "waited" on for resolution before the callback in `.then` is (or .done in jqueery speak) is called

Comment: however, since `populateStreamerCards` doesn't return anything, the code is doomed to fail

Comment: possible solution - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/prdsbpy6/

Comment: I'm on my phone so I won't attempt to write a proper answer right now. What I will do is point you to an article that helped me understand how [Promises] work. I highly recommend that you take the time to understand this, as your decision will greatly impact your ability to write more efficient code. Hope that helps.  (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

Comment: Also, consider Promise.all instead of for loop since as the code reads now your $.when code will run after the first promise resolves (and for every subsequent resolved promise). It doesn't look like that's what you're going for. I assume you want populateStreamerCards() to finish running for every item in the streamers array, and Then your .done(function) should run. If that's the case, promise.all().

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for taking a stab at it. I added some alerts in each function and noticed that parts of each function were still going out of order.

Comment: @quarterpi Thanks for the documentation. I'll check it out. You are correct in that I was looking for all of populateStreamerCards() to finish before running the other function. I'll read into promise.all. That was part of Jaromanda's solution as well

Comment: @quarterpi The documentation you shared helped a lot with my understanding. Instead of the for loop around the Ajax, I put the loop around a section of Promise.all code. I didn't need to use $.when. It made the code simpler, easier to read and works well. Thanks!

Comment: @Wes that's great! I personally found that article to be particularly informative and well written. It helped me with my understanding and I'm glad I could pass it along to you.